# The same Android app as free app and paid on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

I have an Android app at Google Play that is a free app with some ads. I'd like to publish exactly the same app as a paid app just without the ads.
Isn't that against Google Play policy?

The same question applies to Samsung Apps and Opera App Store.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about app store policy, not programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Isn't that against Google Play policy?

No, it's not. Many publishers do exactly the same.

Answer (score 3):

there are plenty of apps that have an ad version and a version without ads that you pay for. most however have implemented IAP so you dont have to maintain 2 apps

Comment: What is IAP ? can you please tell me how to do it.

Comment: I think he was trying to talk about in-app Billing Product: See at: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html

Comment: In App Purchases http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html

Answer (score 0):

That is what many apps do, especially before *in-app purchases* became so mainstream. Just name it something different. For example, if you current app is called *MyApp*, just name your paid version *MyApp Pro*.

You state:

> I'd like to publish exactly the same app as a paid app just without the ads.

And yes, it is against policy to release a free app, then make users pay for it. But that is not what you are actually doing. *The same app just without ads* means an ad-free version - not the same app.

One thing you should consider while maintaining multiple apps is to have a shared library. Or if you are using [gradle](/questions/tagged/gradle) to build your code, look into how you can have one build process to make both the free and paid versions. This will allow you to have a single code base, and not have to maintain code in multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

No the only thing is to tell the people about your ad-free app and you done :)!
read the google [policy](http://play.google.com/about/play-terms.html) because if i could flag it as not real question i would